# debugging GWT Overlay object in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, debugging, gwt, gwt2, jsni

I am using JS Overlay objects in my GWT application. When Debugging the application, I am not able to see the value of Overlay object. Is it a limitation of Using GWT overlay objects.?
Is it because Overlay object is a native Object..? If it is a limitation, Is there any future plan to bring debugging support for Overlay objects in GWT.?

[I am not able to upload images. So typing what I see in the debug window]

```
> customer= JavaScriptObject$ (id=52)
  > hostedmodeReference= JsValusOOPHM (id=183)
    > value= BrowserChannel$JsObjectRef (id=188)
        refId= 2
```

GWT version 2.5.1

Comment: I see below two tickets related to my question. but not sure whether it is plugged into eclipse debugging.
https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=2912
https://code.google.com/p/google-plugin-for-eclipse/issues/detail?id=95

Comment: A block of code would be helpful, are you extending JavaScriptObject because if so you can print it with Window.alert(new JSONObject(customer).toString());

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Overlay types in GWT are a very special beast and are implemented using bytecode rewriting. See https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/wiki/OverlayTypes for (maybe a bit outdated) details.

As Suresh [points out in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17765208/debugging-gwt-overlay-object-in-eclipse#comment25915706_17765208), there's low-level support for it in GWT but then IDEs have to use it for a seamless integration.

[Pending that integration](https://code.google.com/p/google-plugin-for-eclipse/issues/detail?id=95), you can use the utility class directly in the “watch” view (or similar) in your IDE during a debugging session:

```
com.google.gwt.core.ext.debug.JsoEval.call(MyJso.class, myJso, "myMethod")
```

Answer (score 1):

This will print the json string from the JavscriptObject.

```
// Print it to the log
GWT.log(new JSONObject(customer).toString()); 

// Popup window
Window.alert(new JSONObject(customer).toString());
```